# Store huge amount of data in memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am looking for a way to store several gb's of data in memory. The data is loaded into a tree structure. I want to be able to access this data through my main function, but I'm not interested in reloading the data into the tree every time I run the program. What is the best way to do this? Should I create a separate program for loading the data and then call it from the main function, or are there better alternatives?

thanks
Mads

Answer (score 6):

I'd say the best alternative would be using a database - which would be then your "separate program for loading the data".

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a POSIX compliant system, then take a look into [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap).

I think Windows has another function to memory map a file.

Comment: "If you are using linux": `mmap()` is POSIX, not only linux: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html

Answer (score 3):

You could probably solve this using [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory), to have one process that it long-lived build the tree and expose the address for it, and then other processes that start up can get hold of that same memory for querying. Note that you will need to make sure the tree is up to being read by multiple simultaneous processes, in that case. If the reads are really just pure reads, then that should be easy enough.

Comment: This. (alternatively, use indices instead of pointers and store the tree in a mapped file on disk).

Comment: Be careful about addressing pointers in shared memory from tree structures. Shared memory contents has relative addressing, so, traveling through the tree pointers will crash the program. Boost has an special offset pointer for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into a technique called a [Memory mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: +1 for one of the simplest solutions that will also support data bigger than RAM out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to configure a cache server and put data there.

Look into [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-server):

> Ehcache is an open source, standards-based cache used to boost
>   performance, offload the database and simplify scalability. Ehcache is
>   robust, proven and full-featured and this has made it the most
>   widely-used Java-based cache.

It's written in Java, but [should support any language you choose](http://ehcache.org/about/features):

> The Cache Server has two apis: RESTful resource oriented, and SOAP.
>   Both support clients in any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You must be running a 64 bit system to use more than 4 GB's of memory. If you build the tree and set it as a global variable, you can access the tree and data from any function in the program. I suggest you perhaps try an alternative method that requires less memory consumption. If you post what type of program, and what type of tree you're doing, I can perhaps give you some help in finding an alternative method.

Since you don't want to keep reloading the data...file storage and databases are out of question, but several gigs of memory seem like such a hefty price.

Also note that on Windows systems, you can access the memory of another program using ReadProcessMemory(), all you need is a pointer to use for the location of the memory.

Comment: Two little notes: The limit of what you can map under 32 bit Windows is more around 1.3 to 1.4GB with normal boot (2.3 to 2.4GB with /3G and LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag), not 4GB. Also, ReadProcessMemory is a kind of memcpy (between processes), so it is not likely something one would want to use. The overhead would be forbidding.

Answer (score 0):

You may alternatively implement the data loader as an executable program and the main program as a dll loaded and unloaded on demand. That way you can keep the data in the memory and be able to modify the processing code w/o reloading all the data or doing cross-process memory sharing.

Also, if you can operate on the raw data from the disk w/o making any preprocessing of it (e.g. putting it in a tree, manipulating pointers to its internals), you may want to memory-map the data and avoid loading unused portions of it.